# Read a file line into seperate variables

Tags: java

I have a file for which I want to read each integer into a **separate** variable until new line is encountered from a file which would look similar to this.

```
1 3 5
2 3 3
4 3 3
```

In C, I could use:

```
fscanf(file_desc, "%d, %d, %d \n", &varA, &varB, &varC); //just wrote that here..syntax could be wrong
```

Is there a way of doing that with Java? So read each number into a separate variable.

Comment: You could pass in each line using a Scanner, and then make a new Scanner that parses each of those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we have syntactic sugar like that for that in Java.

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), reading lines with `nextLine()`, splitting them with `split(" ")`, and using `Integer.parseInt()` to parse to an integer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
    List<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] numbers = s.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (String n : numbers)
            try {
                numbersList.add(Integer.parseInt(n));
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.err.println("Not an integer: " + n);
            }
    }
    System.out.println(numbersList);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see an example?

Comment: @lecardo there you go

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("your file")));
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] ints = s.split(" ");
            a = Integer.parseInt(ints[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(ints[1]);
            c = Integer.parseInt(ints[2]);
        }
```